# Update statements in a large stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have 8000 update statements in a stored procedure. When I try to `CREATE OR ALTER` the stored procedure, I get this error - `Query failed: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.`

I `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of the procedure thinking that might be the issue, but that didn't fix it. Any ideas? I am on Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, I inherited it. @BrianOgden

Comment: What SLO?  You might need to bump it up for the DDL to succeed.

Comment: Ya SPROC like that should not exist in the world, gives SPROCS a  bad name :). My guess if you move from Azure Sql Server to your own managed instance or your own SQL Server Machine the error will go away...

Comment: Why does it contain 8,000 `UPDATE` statements? Surely that can be changed to be but a few. Just because you inherited it doesn't mean you can't change it. Clearly whomever wrote it had no idea what they were doing as no one sane would write an SP that contain 8,000 different `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: What query tool are you using to run the DDL? May be try something else as there may well be an error being thrown.

Comment: @TomC I am using Azure Data Studio.

Comment: One thing you could try, if its not possible to fix your update statements in any other way, is to break it into part1 and part2, with part1 calling part2 at the end. That may allow you to at least modify the proc.

Answer (score 0):

Close all your current sessions and refresh your DB Server.

Run Index Fragmentation and then Update your statistics using the query. Recommend to do in non-peak hours. Online de-fragmentation is recommended.

Now try to alter your stored procedure.